How to find the image of $f(x) = \sin x+\cos x$?
I would like to find the image of the function
$f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$.
What's wrong with the solution I did?
$$\begin{align}
-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1 \\
-1 \le \cos(x) \le 1 \\
-2\le \sin(x)+\cos(x)\le 2
\end{align},$$
with $\operatorname{Im}(f)=[-2,2]$
Many thanks to the helpers.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

If you think the image of $f$ contains $2$, then you need to exhibit an $x$ coordinate making that happen.

Hint: prove $\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4)$.

Find the maximum and minimum attained by the function $f(x)=\sin x+\cos x$. Then intermediate value property of continuous functions determines the image.

Both addends reach a maximum value of $1$. For the sum to reach $2$ you need both sine and cosine to equal $1$ at the same time, that is for the same $x$ value. However, when one of them reaches $1$ the other one is $0$. So there is no such $x$ which makes $\sin x+\cos x = 2$. As a result, your answer is wrong.

Yes, the inequality holds but the $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is a subset of $[-2, 2]$ and equality may not hold. You must check it! For example, can you find $x$ such that $\sin(x) + \cos(x) =2$?

A proper subset, you may add. :)

What's wrong with that solution is that it only proves that $\mathrm{Im}(f)\subset[-2,2]$ (which is true), but not that $\mathrm{Im}(f)=[-2,2]$ (which is false).
For instance, if
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=1\\
-1&\text{if }x=-1\\
0&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}
$$
and $g=-f$, then it is also true you always have $-1\le f(x)\le1$ and that $-1\le g(x)\le1$. However, $f+g$ is the null function and so $\mathrm{Im}(f+g)=\{0\}$.

Let's offset the argument by a substitution: $$ x=v-d $$ with $$ d=\pi/4. $$
For this value of $d$ we have $$ \sin d = \cos d = 1/\sqrt 2. $$
By applying basic trigonometric identities for sine and cosine of a sum we get:
$$\sin x + \cos x$$
$$= \sin(v-d) + \cos(v-d)$$
$$= \sin v\cos d - \cos v\sin d + \cos v\cos d + \sin v\sin d$$
$$= \sin v\,(\cos d+\sin d) + \cos v\,(\cos d - \sin d)$$
$$= 2\cdot\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\,\sin v + 0\cdot\cos v$$
$$= \sqrt 2\,\sin v$$
Obviously, $v = x+\pi/4$ is any real number, so $\sin v$ assumes all values in $[-1, 1].$
Finally, $\sin x + \cos x$ image is $[-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2] \color{red}{\subsetneq [-2, 2]}.$

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have $$|\sin x+\cos x|\le \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}=\sqrt{2}$$ The equality holds if $\sin x=\cos x$ which occurs at $\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4.$ The corresponding values are  $\pm \sqrt{2}.$ By the IMV we get that the range is equal $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}].$
